# Extracting the URL from the query string

Tags: node.js, url, express, query-string

Consider a url like this:

http://some-site.com/something/**http://www.some-other-site.com**

I am trying to log to the console the **bold** part from the query string i.e. the second http:// using the following method.

```
app.get("/something/:qstr",function(req,res){

    console.log(req.params.qstr);   
};
```

However this will only work until the http: --> as soon as the // is encountered it is no longer included in the `req.params.qstr` I'd like to know how to get the entire URL string. How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: That's not a valid URL; the URL component in the path would have to be [URL encoded.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) That may be the reason why it's not working for you. Where are you getting this data from?

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is to save the second URL to my db whenever it is entered after something, I am trying to extract that part and save to my db.

Comment: But why do you receive URLs that are structured in this broken way in the first place?

Comment: It's a project I am working on where you can go to my website i.e. some-site.com navigate to the /something/ route... Enter a URL in proper format, and once it is entered it will save to the Db. Do you know how to extract the URL here?

Comment: Use the expression: `/something/:qstr(.*)`

Comment: As said, the URL in the route should be properly URL encoded from the start. Not doing it introduces side effects (like `#anchors` not working the expected way) and it's possible your problem will go away completely.

Comment: @hjpotter92 that did not work. req.params.qstr will still only show http: and not the entire url.

Comment: @Pekka웃 have you seen those URL-shorteners that use the same structure? You go to their website and enter a NEW url and are able to receive a shortened one which redirects you to the original? How are they doing this then?

Comment: Can you link to an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, using a regex:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.get(/^\/something\/(.*)/, function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.params[0]);
    res.json({ok: true});

});

app.listen(3333, () => console.log('Listening on 3333'));
```

When you run:

```
curl http://localhost:3333/something/http://www.some-other-site.com
```

the server prints:

```
http://www.some-other-site.com
```

as you wanted.

The `res.json({ok: true});` is there only to return some response so the `curl` will not hang forever.

Comment: you can change res.json to res.send() and you'll get a 200 back

Comment: This solved it thanks. can you please quickly explain the regex? It's just saying grab everything until after the slash right?

Comment: If I do app.get() it will work however if do the same thing with app.use it will not. app.use(/\/new\/(.*)/, error); - error.js --> 

router.get("/",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.params[0])
    res.send(req.params[0])
});

please advise

Comment: @JohnNoob I updated the regex to be `/^\/something\/(.*)/` which means - anything that starts with `/something/` and then anything captured as `req.params[0]`. `app.use` is different than `app.get` - see: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: Yes thank you, I'm comfortable with JS but new to Node so still finding my way around. I aspire to be as knowledgeable with Node as you one day.